# JMeter EOF does not exist

Tags: json, api, jmeter

In JMeter, my HTTP Request performs a POST of a JSON-formmated body data. Within that request, I have a Listener (Save Responses to a File) to save the response.
[see image: Listener: Save Resonses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7goeG.png)

I need to post this response within a 2nd HTTP Request, so I created a Config Element (CSV Data Set Config) containing the basename as follows:
[see image: Config Element: CSV Data Set Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5GDN.png)

In the 2nd HTTP Request, I added the following to the Body Data with the hope of posting the contents of the saved file as the body of this second request.

```
 ${__FileToString(/Users/C13018/Documents/results/${__eval(${JSON_FILE})}.json,,)}
```

When I run it, I get a Stop Thread Exception caused by "... file 'EOF'.json does not exist."

If I change this to the following using the hard-coded filename, it works.

```
 ${__FileToString(C:/Users/C13018/Documents/results/${__eval(RecordTest_1)}.json,,)}
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I guess I was taking some of the examples provided by others "too literally". The correct payload body needed to be

```
${__FileToString(${__eval(${JSON_FILE})},,)}
```

Additionally, I removed the  CVS controller element because it was no longer needed after correctly fixing the HTTP body to use the Variable Name (*newRecordFile*) defined in the Listener.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but for a different reason. In my case, the CSV Data Set Config file had a a couple of empty lines at the end. Because of this, JMeter was randomly picking the nonexistent "EOF".json every now and then during the tests, thus failing the call.
I simply had to remove the empty lines from the .csv in order to fix the problem.